# My labels column has all of a sudden collapsed!

Tags: gmail

My labels column has all of a sudden collapsed and now only when I hover over them does it expand. How do I get the default back to always show all of my labels?

Comment: Could you add a GIF example so it would be more clear what you mean?

Answer (score 62):

You are saying your label column looks like this and only shows the wording when you hover regardless of the width of the browser (no responsive web design causing it to collapse).

[image: Gmail Sidebar Collapsed]

Take a look at the hamburger menu (with a hover tip that says "Main Menu"). It is really just a toggle to pin or hide the text on the sidebar. Not actually a traditional menu. A bit non-intuitive in my opinion.

[image: Gmail Sidebar Toggle]

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! I reverted back to old Gmail because my sidebar would not stay open!

Comment: really annoying and not fitting google to do something like this :(